# SQL Server UPDATE trigger errors for quantity check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will prevent a user from updating the quantity in my `orderdetails` table if the quantity is greater than the `unitsinstock` on the `products` table.

I'm new to this and tried reading what I could find in the T-SQL docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) from Microsoft but didn't find it too helpful.

Here's the error I get:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_check_qty, Line 281 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_qty
ON orderdetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @prod_id INT

    SELECT @prod_id = productid
    FROM inserted

    IF (SELECT products.UnitsInStock
        FROM products
        WHERE products.productid = @prod_id) >= (SELECT orderdetails.quantity
                                                 FROM orderdetails
                                                 WHERE orderdetails.productid = @prod_id)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'Not enough units in stock.'
    END 
GO
```

Comment: Triggers are not a sane way to do this. Consider creating a stored procedure that claims/reserves the stock for an order in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid) transaction.

Comment: The error message is also quite clear. What about it don't you understand?

Comment: Also, your trigger implies that the table will only ever have 1 row at a time updated. If you update more than that, it's not going to work as intented.

Comment: @Andomar I agree and would have done a stored procedure however for this particular question I am being told to create an UPDATE trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear, one of your selects returns more than 1 value, so the comparison can't be made because it doesn't know which of those values must be compared.

This is the code that you wanted to write (you need to retrieve the product quantity only for the updated orderdetail) :

```
create trigger tr_check_qty
ON orderdetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @orderdetail_id int
DECLARE @prod_id int
select @orderdetail_id = orderdetailid, @prod_id = productid
FROM inserted
IF(
    select UnitsInStock
    from products
    where productid = @prod_id
)
>= 
(
    select quantity
    from orderdetails
    where orderdetailid = @orderdetail_id and productid = @prod_id
)
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Not enough units in stock.'
END 
GO
```

This will only work if you modify records one by one (so the inserted virtual table has only one record). But sooner or later you will try to update several orderdetails on a single instruction, and your trigger won't loop through every product updated. To do so you will need a cursor.

I have also replaced your rollback with a raiserror (which also rollbacks the transaction).

```
create trigger tr_check_qty
ON orderdetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @orderdetail_id int
DECLARE @prod_id int
DECLARE UpdatedProducts CURSOR FOR select orderdetailid, productid from inserted
OPEN UpdatedProducts
FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatedProducts INTO @orderdetail_id, @product_id
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  IF(
      select UnitsInStock
      from products
      where products.productid = @prod_id
  )
  >= 
  (
      select quantity
      from orderdetails
      where orderdetailid = @orderdetail_id and productid = @prod_id
  )
  BEGIN
    CLOSE UpdatedProducts
    DEALLOCATE UpdatedProducts
    RAISERROR('Not enough units in stock.', 20, -1)
  END
  @FETCH NEXT FROM UpdatedProducts INTO @orderdetail_id, @product_id
END
CLOSE UpdatedProducts
DEALLOCATE UpdatedProducts
GO
```

But if you directly join the products table to the inserted virtual table, then you can build a much simpler trigger that does the same checks on every row updated.

```
create trigger tr_check_qty
ON orderdetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF exists(select *
          from inserted
               inner join products on products.productid = inserted.productid
          where inserted.quantity > products.UnitsInStock)
begin
    raiserror('Not enough units in stock.', 20, -1)
end
GO
```

Comment: If there are multiple rows, the trigger won't actually fail; it'll just not work as intented. You can return a dataset with multiple rows when assigning a value to a variable; the variable will just be assigned the last value that was returned in that dataset. Is it a good idea to do so though (especially within a trigger)? No, definitely not. :). As a simple example try `DECLARE @I INT = (SELECT i FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(i) ORDER BY i); SELECT @I;` Notice it has a value of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Marc Guillot, I got the trigger working using the code below to satisfy the two updates (1 allowed, 1 not) in the question.

```
create trigger tr_check_qty
ON orderdetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @order_id int
DECLARE @prod_id int
select @order_id = orderid, @prod_id = productid
FROM inserted
IF(
    select quantity
    from orderdetails
    where orderid = @order_id and productid = @prod_id
)
>= 
(   
    select UnitsInStock
    from products
    where productid = @prod_id
)
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Not enough units in stock.'
END 
GO

/* Should prevent as units in stock are only '3' */
UPDATE OrderDetails
SET Quantity = 5
WHERE OrderID = 10008
  AND ProductID = 21

/* Should allow as units in stock are '35' */
UPDATE OrderDetails
SET Quantity = 10
WHERE OrderID = 10008
  AND ProductID = 14
```

Comment: And at some point things will go "bad" because your trigger does not support statements that update multiple rows. And don't use print in a trigger - it is not intended to provide resultsets or output to the process executing the update/merge statement. You need to throw an error or call raiserror.